# SMTP transport mails are not received

Tags: email, smtp, symfony, postfix-mta

I have deployed a symfony app to the production server, which has a feature that sends emails. I have tested sending mails and they work in Dev/Test.

Here is the log from the production server:

```
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/smtpd[13547]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/smtpd[13547]: 8421142F63: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/smtpd[13547]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] helo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/pickup[13516]: 8CCA642F64: uid=33 from=<no-reply@mydomain.com>
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/cleanup[13549]: 8CCA642F64: message-id=<d1cf79ba9e3b445cc2961af059627f13@mydomain.com>
    Dec 28 12:04:01 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/qmgr[13517]: 8CCA642F64: from=<no-reply@mydomain.com>, size=714, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Dec 28 12:04:02 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/smtp[13551]: 8CCA642F64: to=<rolland.b@live.com>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[104.44.194.233]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.06/0.04/0.45/0.63, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <d1cf79ba9e3b445cc2961af059627f13@mydomain.com> Queued mail for delivery)
    Dec 28 12:04:02 lamp-512mb-fra1-01 postfix/qmgr[13517]: 8CCA642F64: removed
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how is your config different in prod ? (`config_prod.yml`)

Comment: nothing on the swiftmailer configurations

Comment: What is the problem? The log you posted looks ok (a mail is being delivered to a recipient at Live/Hotmail)

Comment: Hotmail/Live might suppress your emails silently, try using another recipient address for testing.

Comment: That's true. Is Microsoft blocking it. It works with other addresses. I need to look into their policies and adjust the code for sending mails, or putting them together